# How to solve for matrix D in $ABC^{T}DBA^{T}C=AB^{T}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So the problem I'm having is trying to solve for matrix $D$ in the following equation, assuming the matrices are all $n\times n$ size and invertible. 
$$
D ~~\text{in}~~ ABC^{T}DBA^{T}C=AB^{T}
$$

Comment: hints: $$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$$

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Use the following facts: $$(A^{-1})^T=(A^T)^{-1}, ~~~(AB)^T=B^TA^T$$
For example $ABC^TDBA^TC=AB^T$ becomes $BC^TDBA^TC=B^T$, cause according to your assumption all matrices are invertible and of course they are squares .

Comment: @Alexander: I think you don't need to epitomize the matrices. Just play with them. So you will get $C^TDBA^TC=B^{-1}B^T$ so $DBA^TC=(C^{-1})^TB^{-1}B^T$ and...

Comment: I made up matrices A, B, C, D and did the operation ABCD. I then tried ABCD x C^-1, but I didn't get ABD. Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: @Alexander: I don't get why did you do that manipulations. Multiplications between square matrices are not commutative in general and that is why you didn't get $ABD$ from such that way. ;-)

Comment: ohhh I see! well It's because I also tried ABCD x A^-1 and I didn't get BCD, I should have written that example instead of with C^-1. But I have to do A^-1 x ABCD to get BCD! Thanks!

Comment: My mistake, I couldn't visualize where to do the multiplication based off of an example with 2 matrices.

Comment: I am glad of helping you. Nothing can make a teacher the feelings of happiness but giving someone a proper answer. Welcome Alexander. ;-)

Comment: So to be sure, the answer would be D = (C^-1)t B^-1 Bt C^-1 (A^-1)t B^-1? Also, are you using some kind of program to write math symbols? or alt functions?

Comment: @Alexander: Ya. You got it.

Comment: Nice hint and time spent following up! +1